# How can I make a 'Private' ResourceDictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a Style that only exists within the context of a ResourceDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771328/how-to-make-a-style-that-only-exists-within-the-context-of-a-resourcedictionary)

I'm building a complex ResourceDictionary which will expose ControlTemplates I want to share with projects that include that ResourceDictionary. However, this ResourceDictionary contains a series of supporting styles and templates which I *don't* want available to the projects. How can I do this?

For example:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <!-- Private dictionary items used to set up the publicly usable Omnibox templates -->
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="PrivateDictionary">
        <Thickness x:Key="BaseValueMarginAdjustment">2,0,0,0</Thickness>            
        <!--Base Styles -->
        <Style x:Key="BaseElement" TargetType="FrameworkElement">...</Style>
        <Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="Grid" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseElement}">...</Style>
        <Style TargetType="Selector" x:Key="SelectorStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseElement}">...</Style>
        ...
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <!--Public CONTROL TEMPLATES -->
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:OmniBox}"  x:Key="OBListBoxTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="PART_Grid" Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}">
            <ListBox x:Name="PART_Value" Style="{StaticResource SelectorStyle}" />
            ...
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate ...>
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Note that the above does not work. In particular, the above compiles, but has a runtime error because the ControlTemplates I want publically visible can't find the above private styles like "GridStyle".

---

Tried the following without success as well:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- Private dictionary items used to set up the publicly usable Omnibox templates -->
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>...</ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!--CONTROL TEMPLATES -->
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:OmniBox}"  x:Key="OBTextBoxTemplate">
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you place these Resources for Styles in separate Resource Dictionary? So, across project where you don't want these Resources to be visible, simply don't merge them there.

Suppose you have Resource define in your App.xaml like this -

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Themes/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Themes/Dictionary2.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Suppose your Style Resources exist in Dictionary2.xaml, simply omit the second dictionary from it.

Edit:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Themes/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

You can add the reference of ResourceDictionary1 in your ResourceDictionary2. And wherever you want the reosurces to be used say any UserControl you can always add reference of ResourceDictionary1 there in case you dont want the global reference.

Comment: ResourceDictionary2 depends on ResourceDictionary1. It will not compile without it, so that won't work. Furthermore, if I include ResourceDictionary1 in my application MergedDictionaries, I'm not solving anything - all of the styles in ResourceDictionary1 will be publicly usable by any window, which is **not** what I want. I only want them usable by ResourceDictionary2.

Comment: You can add reference for ResourceDictionary1 to your ResourceDictionary2.

Comment: That was just a reference that how can you add the Resources. You can always add the reference where you want. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but this results in an XamlParseException at runtime, with error message "Item has already been added." Note that the Dictionary is only included in that one spot, nowhere else in the application. There are also no duplicate keys in the file. The error occurs on the line before </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

Comment: Can you show the code where you did this?

Comment: Edited my question to show the code.

Comment: +1 for effort so far though, seriously.

Comment: There might be some other issue. Small sample which i created working fine and is compiling and executing well. However, the purpose is not served because if ResourceDictionary2 holds the reference of ResourceDictionary1 in its merged dictionaries and you only add the reference of RD2 to your UserControl, RD1 will get visible automatically.

Comment: You can make your controls Private by setting the x:FieldModifier="private". I tried for RD too but no help since RD doesn't support x:Name property :(

Comment: Yeah... I'm going to try posting a different question that's a little more poignant.

Comment: It's saying I can't add an x:FieldModifier attribute without an x:Class attribute.

Comment: Yeah, even when i provide it with my custom class name. It crashes at runtime since since RD doesn't extend any class. As a workaround you canalways override the styles where you want. so, instead of hiding it why don't you try override styles which you want in your UserControl?

Comment: My worry is that my styles are constantly inheriting from base styles, building in more features, and I only want the finished products being used. I don't want someone to accidentally use one of the styles that are only intended as an intermediary to one of the finished styles.