# How to make a Style that only exists within the context of a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, dictionary

How can I create a style that only exists within the context of a ResourceDictionary, but not in the context of controls that include that ResourceDictionary?

For instance, I want to be able to have a ResourceDictionary that looks like this:

```
<!-- ControlTemplates.xaml -->
<ResourceDictionary>
    <!-- Private Local styles used to set up the publicly usable templates -->
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxes" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
    <!-- End of Private Local Stuff -->
    <!-- Public Dictionary Resources Follow -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomTextBox">
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxes}" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And then in some other control or window, I want to be able to go:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ControlTemplates.xaml">
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!-- This Should Work -->
        <CustomControl Template="{StaticResources CustomTextBox}">

        <!-- This Should NOT Work! -->
        <TextBox Template="{StaticResources TextBoxes}">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to get quite close to what you are looking for is to move the "private" styles from  `ControlTemplates.xaml` into their own `ResourceDictionary`, and then reference that resource dictionary from within the control templates in ControlTemplates.xaml:

ControlTemplates.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!-- By referencing the ResourceDictionary from within the ControlTemplate's
         resources it will only be available for the ControlTemplate and not for those
         who reference ControlTemplates.xaml -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomTextBox">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ControlTemplatePrivateStyles.xaml" />
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxes}" Text="Some text" />
    </ControlTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

ControlTemplatePrivateStyles.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="TextBoxes" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then the xaml for the window would look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ResourceDictionaryPrivateStyle.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ResourceDictionaryPrivateStyle="clr-namespace:ResourceDictionaryPrivateStyle"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ControlTemplates.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <!-- This works -->
        <ResourceDictionaryPrivateStyle:CustomControl Template="{StaticResource CustomTextBox}" />

        <!-- This does not work, unless you explicitly reference ControlTemplatesPrivateStyles.xaml here in the window-->
        <TextBox Text="Text" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxes}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This way you could not use the "private" styles unless you explicitly reference that resource dictionary. They will not be accessible by just referncing the ControlTemplates.xaml resource dictionary.

Comment: That's very good. IF, however, my ResourceDictionary contains upwards of 100 control templates, all of which are referencing styles from this private dictionary, is there a way to template them all to contain that private ResourceDictionary? i.e. `<Style TargetType="ControlTemplate"><Setter Property="ControlTemplate.Resources"><Setter.Value><ResourceDictionary Source="ControlTemplatePrivateStyles.xaml" /></Setter.Value></Style>` ?

Comment: Unfortunately Styles can only be applied to elements that derive from FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement, and ControlTemplate does not derrive from either of those. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx)